# Menu GUI help in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I can't compile this code because of several errors. Most of the errors are under the initUI() method, which was copied from a tutorial site. How do I fix this?

> ActionEvent cannot be resolved to a type   MenuGUI.java    /Misc/src   line 35 Java Problem
>
> ActionListener cannot be resolved to a type    MenuGUI.java    /Misc/src   line 34 Java Problem
>
> KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a variable  MenuGUI.java    /Misc/src   line 29 Java Problem
>
> KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a variable  MenuGUI.java    /Misc/src   line 32 Java Problem
>
> The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})   MenuGUI.java    /Misc/src   line 34 Java Problem

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MenuGUI extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MenuGUI ex = new MenuGUI();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public MenuGUI()
{
    initUI();
}

public void initUI()
{
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

    JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", icon);
    eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    file.add(eMenuItem);

    menubar.add(file);

    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    setTitle("Simple menu");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Eclipse. How are you compiling this? From the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can compile the code without problems, but I get a runtime exception:

Do you have the picture in the right directory? In your code you try load an icon and when it not exist, you get a NullPointerException

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));
```

Otherwise comment it out, and create the menu item without an icon

```
 JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
```

Comment: It works! Which directory is that file supposed to be? Like I said, I copy and pasted the code from a site, but it doesn't seem to link to a specific directory or anything. However, the site uses Linux while I'm on Windows. Does that affect anything?

Comment: It have to be in the same directory where your MenuGUI.class is

Comment: @Geft no, the environment does not affect anything. rather, its where you placed your image that affects things...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the loading of the ImageIcon. Since no image is found at the correct folder, you are getting a nullpointer exception. The solution is simple: place the "exit.png" image in the same folder as your compiled class file.

Comment: you should use the getClass().getResource() part [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: Technically, you can choose not to do this. Also, you are referring to my old suggestion, which I changed long before you posted your comment. Thanks for the heads up anyway!